# Alternate way to find the dataset Id

Tags: analytics-cloud, einstein-analytics

Is there an alternate way to find the dataset id, other than using Chrome browser ->inspect element ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where in wave are you trying to do this ? Please understand that it becomes easier to answer questions if they contain enough detail and context.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke: any programmatic way would be great, say via API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to [https://{YourInstance}/insights/web/lens.apexp](https://%7BYourInstance%7D/insights/web/lens.apexp) , you will get the JSON Viewer for all your dashboards , lenses & edgemarts (datasets)..

the edgemart section will have the dataset name , alias and the unique id.

you can check [this reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_modify.htm) for more details on the JSON viewer and where all you can use JSON to extend some of the analytics cloud functionalities..

**EDIT**

based on your comment, if you are looking for a programmatic way to get the dataset details, you can refer the [Analytics Cloud Dataset Utils](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils) library.

In specific look into the [DataSetDownloader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sforce/dataset/util/DatasetDownloader.java) class getXMD method which has some reference on how to get Edgemart / Dataset details

Comment: this is a manual process, and I am expecting something that can be fetched programmatically - say via API. Any info regarding this would be great !!

Comment: @Glames I hv updated my answer with some reference.. hope it helps